# How does the convergence sector of a continued fraction depend on the order where it is truncated?

Tags: convergence-divergence, continued-fractions, rational-functions, pade-approximation

Consider these three functions:
$$
f(z) = \sqrt{bz} \cdot \coth \sqrt{bz} 
\\
g(z) = \sqrt{bz} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{I}_{0}( \sqrt{bz} )}{\mathrm{I}_{1}( \sqrt{bz} ) } = 
\sqrt{bz} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{J}_{0}( \mathrm{i}\sqrt{bz} )}{\mathrm{J}_{1}( \mathrm{i}\sqrt{bz} ) }
\\
h(x) = (1+bz)^{1/4}
$$
where $z$ is only imaginary: $z=ix$ (in my case the complex frequency $i\omega$). For $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ I define the order of the argument to be $\nu=1/2$ and for $h(x)$ follows $\nu=1/4$, but I suppose arbitary numbers in the range $0 < \nu < 1$ would be generally possible.

I now follow *Baker* and develop the continued fraction for these three functions.

*Baker, George A.jun.; Graves-Morris, Peter*, Padé approximants., Encyclopedia of Mathematics and Its Applications. 59. Cambridge: Cambridge Univ. Press. xiv, 746 p. (1996). [ZBL0923.41001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0923.41001).

[image]

[image]

I truncate the fractions and rewrite them to obtain a rational function of the form

$$\frac{p(z)}{q(z)} = \frac{a_m z^m + \dots a_1 z^1 + a_0}{b_n z^n + \dots b_1 z^1 + 1}$$

where I always chose $n = m-1$.

And finally I evaluate the results for $z = [10^{-10},10^{10}]$ and determine graphically/numerically when the series/rational function diverges.

---

### Actual Question

**How depends the value $z_{div}$, where the rational functions start to diverge, on the order $m$?**

---

### Guess

As non-mathematician I couldn't find an analyticical solution, but I did some curve fitting, leading to:

$$m_{div} = (k^4 \cdot b \cdot z_{div} )^{1/8\nu}$$

where $k$ *could* be [**Khinchin's Constant**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KhinchinsConstant.html).

The result looks too good to be a random incident, as it fits various $b$ and both cases $\nu=1/2$ and $\nu=1/4$. **So I wonder if there is any theorem which could lead to my guess. Do you have any hints for me?**

Comment: I am unlikely to be able to help but I do wonder: when you say "I truncate the fractions," what guides this truncation?

Comment: @law-of-fives 1) computation time, I need to truncate somewhere, no? 2) In the next step the representation $p/q$ will be implemented on a microcontroller. In my case z is a frequency, means the higher the order of $m$ the higher the frequency range my approximated system can model. On the other hand a high $m$ increases the computation time on my controller, so I may be not able to run it in realtime. An optimum has to be found for always changing $b$, thats why I need that formula.

Comment: The reason I ask is because the leading terms of most general continued fractions are... unstable. You need to get to a point where the adjustment implied by $x'$ in $\cdots + \frac{b}{a + x'}$ is, well, "small." In the case of the binomial expansion, for instance, the terms are shrunk by the odd numbers. _Eventually_ these will outgrow any $z$ and exponent product. But until they do, the c.f. is still sorting itself out. Have you done any work with continued fraction arithmetic.

Comment: @law-of-fives I haven't observed this unstable behaviour. My minimum $m$ is 5, so I guess it already can be considered stable.To what exactly are you referring with your last question? All you can see in this question, is all I ever had to do with continued fractions ;)